# HDFS: How to delete files that match pattern

Tags: bash, hdfs

FI have a list of files mydata.YYYY-MM-DD.log the postfix as a date.  For example: mydata.2018-11-26.log

How do I write hdfs that will delete all files with date postfix is earlier than a arbitrarydate, e.g: 2018-11-20

Thx,

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: If the creation dates on the files are the same as the filename-string, it's possible to do this just with the `find` command.  Check the man page for `find`, particularly the `-ctime` and `-anewer` options, and finally `-delete` to remove whatever is found.

Comment: Thank @Kingsley. Unfortunately,  the creation date is not the same as filename-string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

Find the files with a regex
For each file found, extract the date, compare with the given, take action if lesser.

```
#! /bin/bash

SCRIPT=`basename "$0"`

if [ $# -lt 2 ] ||[ "$1" == "" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ] || [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "/?" ]; then
    echo "$SCRIPT: Usage: [directory-path] [cutoff-date]"
    echo "$SCRIPT: Deletes files in the given path newer than the specified date YYYY-MM-DD"
    exit 1
fi

# TODO - check $CUTOFF_DATE is valid
# TODO - check $DIR is valid
DIR="$1"
CUTOFF="$2"

# Find files ending with YYYY-MM-DD.log
find "$DIR" -iname \*\[0-9\]\[0-9\]\[0-9\]\[0-9\]-\[0-9\]\[0-9\]-\[0-9\]\[0-9\].log |
while read file
do
    date_part=`echo "$file" | rev | cut -c5-14 | rev`
    if [ "$date_part" \< "$CUTOFF" ]; then
        echo "$SCRIPT: should remove \"$file\""
        # rm -f "$file"
    fi
done
```